# How do I handle the closing event of a windows explorer window using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events

I'm working on an application where I have a list of hidden directories in a treeview. When the user double clicks on a folder in the directory structure, I open up that folder using the code:

```
Process.Start(tvHiddenFolderListing.SelectedNode.FullPath)
```

Now, the the files within the folders are hidden as well so when it opens the folder, you cannot see the files (Provided view hidden files and folders is not selected.). What I want to do is:

1) when the folder in the tree view is double clicked, I will un hide the files, then open the folder using the process.start code so users will be able to see the files.

2)When the explorer window that opens up upon double clicking is closed, I want to hide the files again. This is where my query lies.

I figured I have the following options:

1) Handle the onClose event for this explorer window and add the code to hide the folders and files within this event.

2) Create a new form in my project an open the path in the process.start above, in this form. In other words, make my own windows explorer form so I can handle the onClose event of this form accordingly.

3) I know how to get the process ID for the explorer window when I start it using process.start. I could check when the process is killed, or exited and hide the folders then.

In a nutshell, I want users to double click the folder in the tree structure, open up that location in a windows explorer and browse it as they normally would browse any other folder on their computer, but I want to have the ability to specify what happens when that window is closed, i.e. hide the files again.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance on achieving my goal via any of the above mentioned methods or an alternative that you think would be better suited.

Thanks in advance.